# Get max attribute value from XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following `XML` file. I want to get `Max("NR")` using `LINQ`. Could anyone help me to do this? I know how to do this for nodes, but attributes made me confused... :S

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SMPyramid LayerName="qwe" LayerPath="D:\#PYRAMID\qwe" Extension=".png" Meters="100000" RasterSize="4000">
  <Level NR="0" RasterXSize="512" RasterYSize="512" LastTileXSize="416" LastTileYSize="416" MinX="400000" MaxX="500000" MinY="1200000" MaxY="1300000" ScaleFactor="25" TilesCountX="8" TilesCountY="8" />
  <Level NR="1" RasterXSize="512" RasterYSize="512" LastTileXSize="323" LastTileYSize="323" MinX="400000" MaxX="499980.9024" MinY="1200019.0976" MaxY="1300000" ScaleFactor="34.679466666666663" TilesCountX="6" TilesCountY="6" />
  <Level NR="2" RasterXSize="512" RasterYSize="512" LastTileXSize="414" LastTileYSize="414" MinX="400000" MaxX="499738.14613333333" MinY="1200261.8538666666" MaxY="1300000" ScaleFactor="69.358933333333326" TilesCountX="3" TilesCountY="3" />
  <Level NR="3" RasterXSize="512" RasterYSize="512" LastTileXSize="206" LastTileYSize="206" MinX="400000" MaxX="499599.42826666665" MinY="1200400.5717333332" MaxY="1300000" ScaleFactor="138.71786666666665" TilesCountX="2" TilesCountY="2" />
  <Level NR="4" RasterXSize="358" RasterYSize="358" LastTileXSize="358" LastTileYSize="358" MinX="400000" MaxX="499321.99253333331" MinY="1200678.0074666666" MaxY="1300000" ScaleFactor="277.4357333333333" TilesCountX="1" TilesCountY="1" />
</SMPyramid>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You treat attributes exactly the same way you would as nodes. So for example:

```
int maxNr = doc.Descendants("Level")
               .Max(x => (int) x.Attribute("NR"));
```

Note that that will give you the maximum value *of* `NR`, not the `Level` element which contains that number. For that, you'd want to either use `OrderByDescending(...).First()` or use `MaxBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com).

Comment: How would one write this in VB?

Comment: @Priednis: Have you tried running it through a C# to VB converter, or looking at the VB examples of `Max` on MSDN?

Comment: I tried 2 converters but nothing useful came from there.   I am now looking through MSDN. I found a preliminary other solution - as I was looking for max id and it is usually the last item, I can use this:  
`Dim MaxIdElement = EventsFileXML.Descendants("event").Reverse.Take(1)  
Dim MaxId = MaxIdElement.First.Element("id").Value` thanks for your help!

Comment: @Priednis: No, that's not a good approach. All you need to do is learn the lambda syntax for VB. That will be applicable all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@" your XML file path ");
int maxNr = xDoc.Root.Elements().Max(x => (int)x.Element("NR"));
```

After you specify the file path, you can get "NR" using the Element.