# xpath Max DateTime

Tags: xpath, xquery, biztalk

I'm having a problem with xpath query. I have a schema with two DateTime fields and I need the Max Datetime from all the records in the schema.

this is my Xpath:

> xPath_a = "max(/libary/DateTime1)";

any suggestion about how to make it work in Xpath?

Comment: **What** is not working? Which XPath version are you using? I guess the XPath 2.0 integrated in XQuery? And, please add some example input.

Comment: Just to note, since the question is tagged BizTalk, it's a safe bet the OP is using XPath 1.0 since that's what supported by .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the version of XPath and Xslt supported in .Net still 1.0 so that's what BizTalk uses.

XPath 1.0 does not have a max() function.

Since the syntax you posted suggests an Orchestration, the most practical option is a helper class that takes message as a XmlDocument parameter.

This thread has an example of hot to use an XPathDocument and an XmlDocument: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6addfe7-c94f-495b-9e79-35c48844b33f/select-max-value-from-xml-file?forum=xmlandnetfx

This thread provides examples of using XDocument and LINQ: [Get max attribute value from XML using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840647/get-max-attribute-value-from-xml-using-linq)

Comment: I ended up doing with a  query from Oracle by using SQLEXECUTE it was a lot more simpler that way. but I tested your solution and it also workes so thank you very much.