# c# xml show highest value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am totally out of Ideas and my C# / LINQ / XML skills are stills very weak. Maybe someone can help me with a relatively simple task that I don't want to write a whole programm around:

I need to get the Highest Customer-ID in an XML Database that looks somewhat like this:

```
<xml>
  <customers>
    <customer>
      <customerid>a00001</customerid>
      <name>this</name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
      <customerid>a00031</customerid>
      <name>that</name>
    </customer>
```

and so on...

What I have tried so far is a mixture of code I have used for other linq/xml that actually worked, combined with stuff I found here:

```
var readme = XElement.Load("someXML");
int tempHigh;
var highIDs =
    (from va in readme.Elements("customers").Elements("customer")
     where Convert.ToInt32(va.Element("customerid").Value.Substring(2, 5)) > tempHigh
     select Convert.ToInt32(va.Element("customerid").Value.Substring(2,5)));

tempHigh = Convert.ToInt32(highIDs.Element("customerid").Value);

return tempHigh;
```

And something is not working. Anyone have an idea where I don't have to put all the data in an array, sort that array and give out the first element (because that is my only Idea left but seems a bit too much)

Comment: but why don't use LINQ and query directly the XML ? See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840647/get-max-attribute-value-from-xml-using-linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int highestId = readme
    .Elements("customers")
    .Elements("customer")
    .Select(cust => Convert.ToInt32(cust.Element("customerid").Value.Substring(1))
    .Max();
```

Comment: in this case .Substring(2) would be better since the customerid might get more digits as the number of customers grows.

Comment: why you start from 2 shouldn't it be 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

or more concise using a combination of linq/xpath

```
int id = readme.XPathSelectElements("/customers/customer/customerid").Max(cid => int.Parse(cid.Value.Substring(1)));
```